# How do I find the terminal command for anything?

Tags: command-line

I love creating hotkeys to open programs and menus, but sometimes I can't figure out what the command for something is. For instance, it took some Googling to find out that the system monitor is opened with `gnome-system-monitor`

Is there anyway to figure out the terminal command for *any* program or menu (such as keyboard shortcuts or display settings) in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `apropos`. Just type `apropos <KEYWORD>` in the Terminal where `<KEYWORD>` is your search string.

```
$ apropos monitor
dbus-monitor (1)     - debug probe to print message bus messages
gnome-system-monitor (1) - view and control processes
gvfs-monitor-dir (1) - Monitor directories for changes
gvfs-monitor-file (1) - Monitor files for changes
inotify (7)          - monitoring filesystem events
iotop (8)            - simple top-like I/O monitor
ip-monitor (8)       - state monitoring
ip-netconf (8)       - network configuration monitoring
jconsole (1)         - Java Monitoring and Management Console
jstat (1)            - Java Virtual Machine Statistics Monitoring Tool
mmcli (8)            - Control and monitor the ModemManager
perf_event_open (2)  - set up performance monitoring
perfmonctl (2)       - interface to IA-64 performance monitoring unit
rtmon (8)            - listens to and monitors RTnetlink
sa-check_spamd (1)   - spamd monitoring script for use with Nagios, etc.
smartctl (8)         - Control and Monitor Utility for SMART Disks
smartd (8)           - SMART Disk Monitoring Daemon
smartd.conf (5)      - SMART Disk Monitoring Daemon Configuration File
syndaemon (1)        - a program that monitors keyboard activity and disables the touchpad when the keyboard is being used.
xconsole (1)         - monitor system console messages with X
XF86VidModeGetMonitor (3) - Extension library for the XFree86-VidMode X extension
xgamma (1)           - Alter a monitor's gamma correction through the X server
```

To get more information about one of the commands you can use `man gnome-system-monitor`

Answer (score 2):

There is no "standard way" that I know of. (Which doesn't mean there isn't) Sometimes it's quite easy to find a command, sometimes it isn't. E.g. when looking at the process list, Google Chrome shows up as `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`, but it is required to start the browser with `/usr/bin/google-chrome`. So here are some methods which can help you.

---

When dealing with an UI application, you can run `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`, and then click on the window in question. This may give you some hints for the executable name, such as

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-system-monitor", "Gnome-system-monitor"
```

---

Also, you can use the default file browser, navigate to `/usr/share/applications` and search for the icon of the program. Then right click it, select "Open with" and select a text editor. This launcher file will contain a line like:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
```

---

If you happen to know the name of the package the program was shipped with, you can use dpkg to look up the files shipped with this package using the `-L` switch. Also grepping for terms like "bin" can be of help:

```
$ dpkg -L gnome-system-monitor | grep bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that you can look programs up in the repositories to find the terminal command.

[image: gnome system monitor in the repositories]

The text after "version" before the first space is the terminal command for this program.

Comment: No, this is the name of the package. But the package name doesn't have to be the same as the program/command. Also you can have lots of programs inside one package.